# Passing value of variable counted in main()

Tags: c

Dears,
Could you please help me with the following issue? I am a noob in programming in C. I am counting the number of values in the main function.
I need to pass those values to a different function. For example
in main a =5 and b=10.

```
int main()
{
a=5;
b=10;
}
float f(float data[a][b], int i){
...
}
```

Thank You for your help.

Comment: Are those global or local variables?

Answer (score 1):

In C you'll often want to use a 1D array of size `[n*m]` instead of a 2D array `[n][m]`. These are easier to pass in and manipulate, and only require a tiny bit of work to get the offsets correct. In this case `float*` and two size parameters would be enough to know what you're working with, like:

```c
float f(float* data, int w, int h, int i) {
  // ...
}
```

Where you call that like:

```c
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
   int w = 5;
   int h = 10;
   float data[w*h];

   f(data, w, h, i);

   return 0;
}
```

It's worth noting a few things about C:

- Arguments are passed in *by value*, which means they're copied. For large structures this can be painful if you pass them in as-is instead of as pointers. `float x[1024][1024]` is a *lot* of data to copy. `float* x` to the same data is a handful of bytes, it's trivial.
- Functions should accept arguments for any parameters they need. This is the standard way of flowing data from one section of the code to another. It helps keep things contained as well.
- Avoid using global variables as an easy way out of this.

Comment: Thank You for your help. I wanted to do double array because I have ready different functions that are doing through by columns. If there is no other way, I will try and rewrite those functions.

Comment: You need to pass in as pointers in order for this to work efficiently. You can pass by value but it gets ugly.